# react-table v7 always remount?

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I'm using react-table v7 for the first time.  My rows have stateful components in them - essentially a stateful key/value selector in each row (inside a cell of course).

I notice that the whole render tree unmounts and remounts when there is a state change to the table - eg if I select a row or insert a new row programatically.  This of course causes my stateful components to be remounted and re-initialised.

I'm in limbo trying to reason about why this happens.  It isn't very desirable, or necessary and actually why does it happen. Does anyone know?

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-ives-4cq9s

Comment: Do you have unique keys set up on your rows? If the keys change, then react will think of them as different component and unmount/remount.
In order to help you specifically, we'll need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @ZacharyHaber Thanks for responding. I believe this illustrates the issue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-ives-4cq9s

My methodology for debugging the remount might be suspect, but the problem is illustrated non-the-less.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you were correct, the debugging methodology was so suspect, it's actually the cause of the problem!

All jokes aside, the issue was that the `DebugUnmount` component was being recreated every time the `App` function body was called.

This meant that because it's a new `DebugUnmount` function, React considered it a completely different component and would unmount the old and remount the new since it's an entirely new children tree according to React's diff engine.

Here's the same codesandbox, but with the inner component no longer being re-created every render:

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-moon-ku89t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: :explodinghead: of course it was. Thanks Zachary .  Back to debugging my original problem which presumbly does exist :)